# Where would I find the equivalent of the monodevelop executable for Visual Studio for Mac in?

Tags: macos, monodevelop, macos-sierra, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to debug a problem similar to the following (except with Visual Studio for Mac) in a similar manner: [Monodevelop - runs only using sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635148/monodevelop-runs-only-using-sudo)

The root of my problem seems to be file permissions issues, as detailed here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/88506/access-denied-to-packages-folder-on-macos

I'd like to try running it using sudo if nothing else, and potentially debug the issue with `dtruss`, but I haven't been able to locate the executable to trigger from the shell.

Where would I find it?

Comment: Try `find  /Applications  ~/Applications -type f | grep -Ei "mono|devel"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the VisualStudio app in /Applications/Visual Stuido.app/Contents/MacOS, and executing VisualStudio under sudo did resolve the issue of access to the packages folder. I will see what I can do to debug using `dtruss` though I've not used it before. Any tips would be appreciated

---

It looks like I can't really mimic the `strace` solution with `dtruss` because I have to use `sudo` with `dtruss` regardless. If anyone can point at a way of comparing the sudo and non-sudo execution on MacOS like they do here [Monodevelop - runs only using sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635148/monodevelop-runs-only-using-sudo#answer-32772022) it would be greatly appreciated.

I tried the following but it's not allowed:

```
sudo dtruss sudo ./VisualStudio
```

---

I found the reason why I needed to use sudo to open Visual Studio for Mac. I incorrectly used sudo when I cloned the repository. I had used sudo because I was confused by the failed authentication message with TFS previously. After I removed the solution folder and re-cloned the repository without sudo Visual Studio for Mac worked correctly.

As a side note, the only way I was able to authenticate from Git to TFS was by enabling credential caching: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/permanently-authenticating-with-git-repositories-776639846.html#PermanentlyauthenticatingwithGitrepositories-OSX